# Angular 2 - Instantiate (Http) Service Manually

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-http

Is it possible to instantiate Http Service manually without having it to put as a constructor argument?

```
export class SimpleGridServer {
    private http: Http;
    constructor(public options: SimpleServerData) {
        http = new Http(.../* Argument here */);
    }
}
```

To instantiate this class.

```
var grid = new SimpleGridServer({/* options */});
```

I want to instantiate this class without having a dependency on Http service for my `component` that import `SimpleGridServer`.
If this is possible, what is the drawback for this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If this is possible, what is the drawback for this scenario?

You need to be in an Angular DI workflow to use Angular stuff.

You can get a handle to angular's injector directly:

```
import {ReflectiveInjector} from '@angular/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Headers} from "@angular/http";
const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
const http = injector.get(Http);
```

Comment: You can use angular 2 DI without the constructor check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37812906/1401751