# Angular2 rc.5 how to inject HTTP_PROVIDERS now that Http is module

Tags: angular

Angular2 rc.5 how to inject HTTP_PROVIDERS now that all are modules...

```
 var injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(
            [
                TodoService,
                TodoAction,
                HTTP_PROVIDERS, // <----- no longer injectable
                TodoStatsModel,
                {provide: CommBroker, useClass: CommBroker},
                {provide: AppStore, useValue: th[![i][1]][1]s.appStore}
            ]);
```

regards,

Sean

Answer (score 4):

For RC5 you have to add the `HttpModule` in `imports array` inside `@NgModule` for more detail check this [link](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: yes it works now ... will soon stop working (if using TypeScript with Web Storm for example you will see an error as HTTP_PROVIDERS  are now deprecated)

Comment: any other solutions?

Comment: i m also searching

Comment: ya :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903607/ng2-rc5-http-providers-is-deprecated

Comment: What if we don't have @ngModue at the time of creation of injector using ReflectiveInjector ??

I need to create injector and call a service (which depends on http) before the root module bootstraps.